# Two many restrictions

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Using only the number 2 several times, form the numbers 2, 22 and 222.

The following operations are available:

- addition
- subtraction
- multiplication
- division
- exponentiation

Each of these operations need to be used exactly 2 times in each of the expressions. Parentheses can be used whenever needed.

Good luck.

Comment: Is concatenation allowed (22)? How about the decimal point (2.2)?

Comment: Neither of the two are allowed. Only the five operations mentioned are. @bobble

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `2 = 2 + (2*2) - (2*2) + ((2^2)/2) - ((2^2)/2)`

> `22 = (2^(2*2)) + (2^2) + (2*2) - (2/2) - (2/2)`

> `222 = ((2+2)^(2+2)) - (2*(2^(2*2))) - (2/(2/2))`